# Does fopen create a file descriptor?

Tags: c, unix, fopen, file-descriptor

Looking at the man page for `fopen` I cannot get a definite answer to this question.

```
FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode);
```

I understand that `fopen` returns a file pointer to a stream but is a file descriptor created as a byproduct? I am trying to make sure that I include the flag `FD_CLOEXEC` on every instance a file descriptor is created. If a file descriptor is in fact created from `fopen` what is the best way to use `fcntl()` when there is no "fd" to use as input.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On Unix (which I assume you're using because you're mentioning `fcntl`) it *does* open a file descriptor, as `fopen(3)` eventually calls `open(2).` You can get that file descriptor via `fileno(3)`.

Answer (score 1):

Since glibc 2.7 you can add `e` character directly to `mode` string. [man 3 fopen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html):

> e (since glibc 2.7)
> Open the file with the O_CLOEXEC flag.  See open(2) for
> more information.  This flag is ignored for fdopen().