# How is the FILE* structure returned by fopen() related to file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, unix

I want to understand how fopen() works.

1. Does fopen() call open() internally?
2. Is the FILE* structure related to file descriptor?
3. If yes, then how is the mapping between to two done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does fopen create a file descriptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642419/does-fopen-create-a-file-descriptor)

Comment: (1) Yes on POSIX systems, though the C standard does not mandate that.  2) No.  (3) The `FILE` structure stores the file descriptor.